# How to efficiently get the value from form UI built with dynamic InputField

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, inputfield

Here is the code that I used to make a tabular UI.

```
DynamicForm[row_, col_] :=DynamicModule[{x = ConstantArray[0, {row, col}], a}, 
    a = {Column[(Row[#] & /@Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, 
          InputField[Dynamic[x[[i, j]]], Number,FieldSize -> Tiny]
          ], {i, 1, row}, {j, 1, col}])]};
    AppendTo[a, {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[]]}];
    CreateDialog[Column[Flatten@{a}, Spacings -> {1, Automatic},Alignment -> Left],
    Modal -> True];
    Dynamic@x
  ];
```

[image]

How can I retrieve the user input form the dialog?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assign your input in `DialogReturn`, e.g. to a variable `return`.  Apart from from this, and omitting your `Dynamic@x` at the end, your code is unchanged:

```
DynamicForm[row_, col_] := 
 DynamicModule[{x = ConstantArray[0, {row, col}], a}, 
  a = {Column[(Row[#] & /@ 
       Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, 
         InputField[Dynamic[x[[i, j]]], Number, 
          FieldSize -> Tiny]], {i, 1, row}, {j, 1, col}])]};
  AppendTo[
   a, {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[return = x]]}];
  CreateDialog[
   Column[Flatten@{a}, Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left],
    Modal -> True]]
```

Now run the dialog and enter your data:

```
DynamicForm[2, 3];
```

[image]

You can obtain the input from `return`:

```
return
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}}

Answer (score 9):

If you want the evaluation to halt until the Dialog returns you can get your code working very simply:

```
 DynamicForm[row_, col_] :=
 DialogInput[{x = ConstantArray[0, {row, col}], a}, 
  Column[Flatten@{{Column[(Row[#] & /@ 
     Table[With[{i = i, j = j}, 
       InputField[Dynamic[x[[i, j]]], Number, 
        FieldSize -> Tiny]], {i, 1, row}, {j, 1, col}])],
     {CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[x]]}}}, 
  Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left]]
```

Note that it's the function DialogInput[] (used here instead of CreateDialog[]) that halts the evaluation, see [How to evaluate following inputs only after finishing CreateDialog](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98648/how-to-evaluate-following-inputs-only-after-finishing-createdialog)

This allows you to just use `DynamicForm` in place of it's input in equations and such for instance: `a=Transpose[DynamicForm[23,34]]` will open a popup and assing `a` to the tranposed result upon pressing the OK button.

**Update**

If you don't want the dialog to return it's value, here is a version that puts the changes into a dynamically updated variable:

```
setDyn[a_Dynamic, val_] := Extract[a, 1, Function[{w}, w = val, HoldAll]];

DynamicForm[a_Dynamic, row_: 2, col_: 2] :=
 CreateDialog[
 DynamicModule[{x = ConstantArray[0, {row, col}]},
 setDyn[a, x];
 Column[{Grid@#1, Row@#2}, Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Center]
     & @@ {
     Table[
      With[{i = i, j = j}, 
       InputField[
        Dynamic[x[[i, j]], 
         Function[{val, nam}, nam = val; setDyn[a, x], HoldRest]], 
        Number, FieldSize -> Tiny]],
     {i, row}, {j, col}],
    {DefaultButton["Close", DialogReturn[]]}
     }]
 ]
```

Called with `DynamicForm[Dynamic[a],4,4]` it will update `a` as you change it.

Comment: Your answer was great too specially I liked the use of `setDyn`.

Comment: Very good answer. Two problem: (1) when DialogInput is created, the first InputField doesn't get the focus: it would be great if it got, because now a click is required to write in the field. (2) when the last InputFiled has the focus, TAB cycles the focus to the first one. That's a bit confusing because, again, a click is necessary, instead of the usual TAB key, to pass the focus to the buttons.