# Assign values to parameters from a list/Matrix using GUI

Tags: dynamic, gui-construction, inputfield

Assume there is a list like:

```
ma={{L1,r1},{L2,r2}};
```

I want to convert the `ma` to a GUI which asks me about the values of L1,r1,L2 and r2 and then allows me to assign values to L1,r1,L2 and r2 as follows:

```
L1=2    r1=0.5
L2=4    r2=0.1
```

Then new matrix `ma` will be:

```
ma={{2,0.5},{4,0.1}}
```

I have no idea how to do that in Mathematica software! Could you please help me with it ?!

---

** **EDITED** **

---

This is my code for the problem:

```
AskUser =
DialogInput[{L1 = "", r1 = "", L2 = "", r2 = ""}, 
Column[{"L1", InputField[Dynamic[L1], Number], "r1", 
 InputField[Dynamic[r1], Number], "L2", 
 InputField[Dynamic[L2], Number], "r2", 
 InputField[Dynamic[r2], Number], 
 Button["Proceed", DialogReturn[{{L1, r1}, {L2, r2}}], 
  ImageSize -> Automatic]}]];
```

Suggested code works properly. However, the `ma` matrix is not a fixed array matrix. For example it can be like:

```
`ma={{L1,r1},{L2,r2},{L3,r3}};`
```

In other words, the `ma` matrix is a **variable matrix** whose general form is like :

```
`ma={{L1,r1},{L2,r2},{L3,r3},...,{Ln,rn}};`
```

(*Thanks SquareOne for the help*) ****EDITED****

Now my question is how I can program a UI which can adapt itself with the `ma` changes in arrays and can accept both Numbers and Symbols for the input fields and having label names beside the input fields?

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial: [Creating Dialog Boxes](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/CreatingDialogBoxes.html)

Comment: Maybe see [How to efficiently get the value from form UI built with dynamic InputField](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/16608/19960)

Comment: @SquareOne :  Thank you so much for your help. The mentioned link is similar to my problem. However, mine is a little bit different. The major problem is that the input box for my problem could be Number or Symbol. The other different is that I also need Label above the input field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Implementation 1

This should produce the desired GUI.

```
askUser[matrix_] := DialogInput[
  Column[{
    Grid[{ToString@#1, InputField[Dynamic[#1], FieldSize -> Tiny], 
        ToString@#2, InputField[Dynamic[#2], FieldSize -> Tiny]} & @@@
       matrix, Alignment -> Left], 
    Row[{CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[matrix]]}]
    }]]

ma = {{L1, r1}, {L2, r2}};
askUser[ma]
```

[image]

```
ma
```

> `{{1, r1}, {L2, 2}}`

```
ma = {{L11, r11}, {L22, r22}, {L33, r33}};
askUser[ma]
```

[image]

> `{{1, r11}, {L22, 0}, {1, r33}}`

It is important to note, that with this implementation the values put into the GUI are assigned to the corresponding parameters of the matrix.

---

### Implementation 2

The GUI of this implementation looks the same as the first one, however no values will be `Set` to the symbols used in the input matrix.

```
askUser2[matrix_] := 
 DialogInput[
  DynamicModule[{localMatrix = ConstantArray[0, Dimensions@matrix]},
   Column[{
     Grid[
      Array[Sequence @@ {ToString@matrix[[#, #2]], 
          InputField[Dynamic@localMatrix[[#, #2]], 
           FieldSize -> Tiny]} &, Dimensions@matrix], 
      Alignment -> Left], 
     Row[{CancelButton[], DefaultButton[DialogReturn[localMatrix]]}]
     }]]]
```

Additionally the possible shapes of the input matrix is less restricted.