# How to evaluate following inputs only after finishing CreateDialog

Tags: functions, evaluation, dialog-window

I have a code which starts with the following Cell:

```
In[1]:= CreateDialog[
  Grid[
   {
    {"Year:", InputField[Dynamic[yyyy], Number]},
    {"Month:", InputField[Dynamic[mm], Number]},
    {"Day:", InputField[Dynamic[dd], Number]},
    {CancelButton[], 
     DefaultButton[DialogReturn[{year = yyyy, month = mm, day = dd}]]}
    },
   Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left
   ]
];
```

Now when I evaluate the whole `Notebook`, the following Cells evaluate before I finish entering the values in the `CreateDialog`.

How to stop all evolutions until the `CreateDialog` window is gone?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`DialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DialogInput.html) instead of [`CreateDialog`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CreateDialog.html)

```
DialogInput[
 Grid[{{"Year:", InputField[Dynamic[yyyy], Number]}, {"Month:", 
    InputField[Dynamic[mm], Number]}, {"Day:", 
    InputField[Dynamic[dd], Number]}, {CancelButton[], 
    DefaultButton[
     DialogReturn[{Year = yyyy, Month = mm, day = dd}]]}}, 
  Spacings -> {1, Automatic}, Alignment -> Left]]
```

---

Documentation:

[image: Mathematica graphics]